# Which State is this

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Which state does the following riddle describe?

> A kingdom that deceives perception
> It is an illusion
> Entry by Magic potion

Comment: Is this an original puzzle?

Comment: @bobble I hope it is

Comment: I don't suppose you mean "California".

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the most precise answer is:

> **Narcotized** (the state of having been treated by a narcotic, or "high".)

Another common word used is:

> **Euphoric** (the state that many popular narcotics leave their subjects.)

But I wonder if the intended answer was simply:

> **High** (slang for being narcotized.)

**Explanation:**

> *A kingdom that deceives perception*

> Narcotics alter perception when the subject is intoxicated and can often lead people to believe they have entered a different plane of existence or realm (kingdom).

> *It is an illusion*

> A lot of what you see when high on narcotics (often called a trip) is an illusion. For instance: some drugs cause people to believe they are seeing sounds waves and radio waves, while others cause people to see hideous monsters and terrifying things, both of which are (probably ;-) ) illusions.

> *Entry by Magic potion*

> Liquid is a common delivery method for narcotics in ritual practices and can be thought of as a potions. Indeed in times past (and even *currently* is some parts of the world), narcotics extracted from plants are boiled into cocktails and ingested in various ceremonies, and these have been called magic potions.

Comment: rot13(pybfr, ybbx ng gur gntf)

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> Hallucinogenic State

Specifically caused by

> mushrooms

*A kingdom that deceives perception*

> Members of the fungi kingdom are known for having hallucinogenic effects

*It is an illusion*

> In this state you can perceive things that are not real

*Entry by Magic potion*

> Psilocybin mushrooms are commonly referred to as Magic Mushrooms

Comment: so, close!!! focus on the wordplay tag

Comment: rot13(Znlor vg'f whfg unyyhpvANGVBA? (Angvba=fgngr jbeqcynl))